# xfce panel weather applet has wrong/missing data

Tags: xfce, indicator, panel, xfce-panel, weather

For the last few days the weather applet in my xfce panel has been either showing "No Data" or showing data that's clearly wrong (completely different from the actual weather).  It used to be fine, and I haven't moved or changed my location settings.

Can anyone think of a way to fix this?  Alternatively, is there another weather applet I could switch to?

This is xfce 4.12, on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xfce-weather-update plugin needs to be updated. You're looking for version 0.8.9 from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-weather-plugin/0.8.9-0ubuntu1/+build/12025316/+files/xfce4-weather-plugin_0.8.9-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Then use

```
sudo dpkg -i /full_path_to_the_deb_file_you_downloaded_above
```

After that, log out and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed xfce4-weather-plugin 0.8.9, which requires Ubuntu 17.04. The problem is the hard-coded source address for the weather data.

Comment: It's xfce4-weather-plugin 0.8.6-1, according to Synaptic.